# Call a method from default package in katalon

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

I have created a default class file for handling the xpath under default package,

```
public class TestObjectHelper {
    /*
     * TestObjectHelper will help the user to handle dynamic xpath
     */
    public static TestObject getTestObjectWithXpath(String xpath) {

        return new TestObject().addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, xpath)
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to use it another package, but it is not identifying the above method.

[image]

import statement

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function the following,

```
import TestObjectHelper
```

or suggest to move this under a separate package let's call it as `com.utilites`

```
import com.utilites.TestObjectHelper
```